# Is there a way to say "crisis averted" in Japanese that retains its sarcastic meaning?

Tags: set-phrases

You know, as in situations that are clearly not crises.

I've looked around but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressions that I think would retain the sarcasm are :

> 「[間一髪]{かんいっぱつ}。」 or 「間一髪だったね。」
>
> 「[危機一髪]{ききいっぱつ}。」 or 「危機一髪だったね。」

A slightly less natural (and more literally translated) phrase would be :

> 「[危機回避]{ききかいひ}したね。」

Comment: Thank you! I think the top two were exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

How about やばかった?  (Might not be exactly the same meaning but is it close enough?)

http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1075588535